# searching for a specific element in default dictionary PYTHOn

Tags: python, loops, defaultdict

**My dict:**

```
expiry_strike = defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'2014-02-21': [122.5], '2014-01-24': [123.5, 122.5, 119.0, 123.0]})
expiry_value = defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'2014-02-21': [-100], '2014-01-24': [-200, 200, 1200, 200]})
```

**My question :**

I want to run a loop
which finds the common element and in `expiry_strike` ( 122.5 in this case ),

and if a common element is found,

then I would like to add the values in `expiry_value` . ( here i want to add -100 + 200 )

Comment: 122.5 or a common element appears on "expiry_strike"

Comment: if it does then i want to add the elements corresponding to 122.5 in "expiry_value"  and preferrably create a new list or update the existing one

Comment: @Dan im stuck in creating an if loop . Somehow its shooting random outputs

Comment: Show us the code you've tried and then we can help you fix it. This is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @Dan dont bother. i got my answer . i do not require your help or as you may call "service"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to show you how you can find the most common element, the rest you should handle yourself.

There is this nice library called `collections` which has a `Counter` class in it. Which counts each element in an iterable and stores them in a dictionary with the keys are the items and the values are the counts.

```
from collections import Counter

expiry_strike = {'2014-02-21': [122.5], '2014-01-24': [123.5, 122.5, 119.0, 123.0]}

for values in expiry_strike.values():
    counts = Counter(values)
    print max(counts , key=lambda x: counts[x])

    # key=lambda x: counts[x] says to the max function
    # to use the values(which are the counts) in the Counter to find the max,
    # rather then the keys itself.
    # Don't confuse these values with the values in expiry_strike
```

This finds the most common element for all different keys in `expiry_strike`. If you want to find the most common element using all the values in `expiry_strike` you have to combine the lists in `expiry_strike.values()`.